# The use of the basic form of a verb with "to" at the beggining of a sentence

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence:

> **To break** it **down**, in any communication there is a sender and a receiver, a message, and interpretations of meaning on both ends.

I cannot get the grammar of it. Does it mean I am going to break it down?

Comment: It's not the grammar you are asking about but the meaning.

Comment: The narrator of the sentence *is* breaking it down. It could be rephrased as *let me break it down for you*.